# Connection to the server was reset while loading the pag in asp.net in firefox over MPLS with 128kpbs

Tags: asp.net, connection, reset, was

I have a asp.net web application hosted in WAN with 128 MPLS connectivity.

Server OS-windows server 2012
IIS-7.5

Browser -Firefox

Its showing " Connection to the server was reset while loading the page" message while doing some activities  from client side over 128 kpbs .

Please help us to trouble shoot the issue

Comment: Use feature [stackoverflow.com/questions/702124/enable-iis7-gzip], that might help you for lower bandwidth connection

Comment: All ready done compression in IIS